# Matlab: the same index value but different rgb value in gray image?

Tags: matlab

I met a problem and it made me crazy :( I read a .jpg file to a matrix, and do the sampling on it. And then I tried to reconstruct the matrix with compressed sensing algorithm. But I found that some of the values in the reconstructed matrix are as same as the original one(at the same position), which means the indexes of the gray images are same, but the rgb value are different. I don't get it why the indexes are same but the rgb can be different???

[image: The first element of the original image]

[image: The first element of the reconstructed image]

Comment: What does MATLAB output if you use the statement `get(gca,'CLim')` on each figure?

Comment: what is the meaning of non-integer index here? Is it possible that the two images have different color maps?